# Slick carousel: Display all items on centerMode

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I am using Slick Carousel with centerMode. Is there a way to display all the items? I don't want them to get overhidden on the screen.

I am using these simple options:

```
$('.your-class').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 2
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eceg5yd/75/)

Comment: By *all* you mean all slides in your carousel? or just three for *n* number of slides?

Comment: If you want all slides to show, then please refer this - https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/544 It is an existing issue of slick slider.

Comment: I mean, if I have 8 slides in total, I want to center only 2 and display the rest on slick-track.

Comment: I understand but you can't show all slides at once using slick slider. That will remove the slider functionality of sliding

Comment: Yeah I know that. I knew that would be tricky but I am trying to apply opacity to the overflow div. Will post my workaround soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can set 'slidesToShow' as 0 so that it will display all the slides at once.

But, as commented by [Developer107](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4719761/developer107) above, "*it won't have the slider functionality of sliding*".

```
$('.your-class').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 0,
  slidesToScroll: 2
});
```

Comment: This causes chrome tab to crash for me with the "Aw snap" error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hidden input field and populate its value with the slider array count, then you can pull the field value in your js and pass it to the slidesToShow option (note: don't forget to turn the value from string to integer!)

```js
  // get the input value which is the count of all slides 
  const slidesCount = document.getElementById( 'slides_count' ).value;

 $( '.photo_gallery_slider' ).slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
 });
 $( '.slider-nav' ).slick({
    // Set the value to slidesToShow option with your own logic or just pass
 the variable with + infront of it which is a shorthand to parse the string into
 integer.
  slidesToShow: ( 5 >= +slidesCount ? +slidesCount : 5 ),
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.photo_gallery_slider',
  dots: false,
  arrows: false,
  centerMode: false,
  focusOnSelect: true
 });
```

```html
<div class="slider-nav">
  <?php 
  $images = get_field('gallery');
  $counter = 0;
    if ($images) : ?>

        <?php foreach ($images as $image) : $counter++; ?>
          <div>
            <?php if($counter == 1) { ?>
              <input id="slides_count" type="hidden" value="<?= count($images); ?>">
            <?php } ?>
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['sizes']['thumbnail']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />  
            <p><?php echo esc_html($image['caption']); ?></p>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```